# Oven temp for dishes with different nominal cooking times?

Tags: temperature, roasting

I want to cook two dishes simultaneously (for efficiency's sake): carrots, which have a nominal cooking temp of 350 F / 180 C for 30 mins. and chicken, which has a nominal cooking temp of 400 F / 200 C for 45 mins. The Seasoned Advice posts I've read on this subject ([here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/67736/combining-dishes-that-need-oven-temps-of-450-425-400-and-350_), [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/80954/cooking-time-and-temperature-for-one-oven-and-two-different-dishes), [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/76805/different-cooking-times-and-different-dishes), and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59559/cooking-more-than-one-dish-that-require-different-temperatures)) suggest the thing to do is cook at the lower temp first, then turn the oven to the higher temp; I can do that if necessary, but if possible I'd prefer to have everything in the oven at once, since the second dish cooks for a while.

If I put the carrots in at 400, how much should I reduce the cooking time? And how severely will it affect the result?

Answer (score 1):

Roasting carrots at 400F for 20 minutes, according to this Food Network recipe: [Roasted Carrots](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/roasted-carrots-recipe-1940444)

I haven't followed that specific recipe, but changing your temp and time accordingly shouldn't create any problem.